# Create Date from this format:YYYYddmm in R

Tags: r, datetime, zoo, posixct, lubridate

I have trouble with date formats. My input data looks like:

```
73;2013120101;   7;  38;   0.1;  99.0;eor
```

Second column `2013120101` is my date column.
I want to import it to work on it in R and eventually it should look like

```
1969 01 02 00:00
```

This way

```
 dwd <- read.csv(file="testdwd.txt",header=T,sep=";",stringsAsFactors=F)
 dwd[,1] <- ymd(dwd[,1])
```

yields 1982-12-01 but I don't know how to get the rest done.

Comment: Do you mean `2013 12 01 01:00`?

Comment: If you "want to work on it in R", you should probably transform it to POSIXct (e.g., use `as.POSIXct`). If you need a specific output format (e.g., when saving the result of your computations to a text file), you can then use `strftime`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try `strptime` and `format`, example

```
d <- "2013120121"
x <- strptime(x=d, format = "%Y%m%d%H")
format(x, "%Y %m %d %k:%M")
## [1] "2013 12 01 21:00" # which gives the desired output
```

`%Y`for year, `%m` for month, `%d` for day, `%k` for hour and `%M` for minutes.

Answer (score 1):

The base function `strptime` handles it correctly:

```
> dwd <- read.csv(textConnection("73;2013120101;   7;  38;   0.1;  99.0;eor"),
                  sep=";",stringsAsFactors=F,head=F)
> strptime(dwd[2],"%Y%m%d%H")
                   V2 
"2013-12-01 01:00:00"
```

Comment: It is not the desired output.

Comment: Then what is the desired output?

Comment: As far as I understood, `2013 12 01 01:00`, but need clarification from OP.

Comment: @Pascal I think OP doesn't mind "dash" `-`, as he was able to get the YMD in date format with `-` and not the HH:MM.

Comment: @zx8754 According to the OP, "eventually it should look like 1969 01 02 00:00".

Comment: Thanks for your fast comments. The strptime command yields the message "Warning message:
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , 1, value = list(sec = c(NA_real_,  :
  provided 11 variables to replace 1 variables"

Comment: In the reduced example i used the object to transform was `dwd[2]`, you need to modify it according to your actual object.

Answer (score 1):

Using lubridate

```
require("lubridate")

#dummy data
x <- read.table(text="73;2013120101;   7;  38;   0.1;  99.0;eor",sep=";")

#reformat
ymd_hms(paste0(x$V2,"0000"))

#output
#[1] "2013-12-01 01:00:00 UTC"
```